# javascript regex exceptions

Tags: javascript, regex

Here Is My Regex Code:

```
/fun(niest|!ny$)?/ig
```

How would I get the word "fun" or "funniest" but not the word "funny" through regex, here is what I have. Is there any way of doing this, if so please help!

Comment: Try it like this  `/fun(?!ny)(niest)?/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundaries `\b` and an optional group `(?:niest)?`:

```
/\bfun(?:niest)?\b/ig
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV4wH2/1)

The pattern matches:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `fun` - literal character sequence `fun`
- `(?:niest)?` - an optional (one or zero occurrences) `niest` literal character sequence (not captured into any group since the group is non-capturing, i.e. used only for grouping)
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

Your [`fun(niest|!ny$)?`](https://regex101.com/r/pA7rA9/1) matches `fun`, or `funniest` or `fun!ny` that is at the end of the string.

Comment: how would this be done with multiple options in the regex which are separated with the |, not as an option phrase/letter but as a word like funny the honey e.g: funny|honey

Comment: `funny|honey` will match either `funny` or `honey`.  Could you be more precise?

Comment: You thought that to match a whole word you need to include a "negative alternative"? That is possible in PHP (PCRE), not in JS. Either use `\b` (as I showed) or non-ambiguous `/(^|\W)(fun(?:niest)?)(?=\W|$)/ig` (but then you will need to use backreferences wisely if replacing, or do more post-processing if matching).

Comment: Another option: (funniest|fun(?!ny))

Comment: @TimothyKanski: If you insist, then again, it should be `/\b(funniest|fun(?!ny\b)\w*)\b/ig` - otherwise I see no use for the lookahead. The thing is, the words are to be matched as whole words in the current scenario, and the 2 words are to be  matched only. If OP says any word *having* or *starting* with `fun` should be matched, but not `funny`, then the lookahead solution will be the best.

Comment: Just an [illustration](https://regex101.com/r/xJ6eP0/1) (but I'd shorten to [`/\bfun(niest|(?!ny\b)\w*)\b/i`](https://regex101.com/r/xJ6eP0/2)).